# One .h file with Two @interface and calling in .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In `.h` file, I have 2 interfaces like this:

```
@interface Main : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *MainView;
@end


@interface Sub : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
@end
```

After that, in `.m` file, I have implementation like this. How can I call `testView` (which is declared in different interface) in `Main` implementation?

```
@implementation Main

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Edited - I can't have or I don't want to have separate .h and .m file because I have many interface like this. I afraid I will need to create a lot of .h and .m file. So, I am combining all those in 1 .h and 1 .m file.

[image]

Comment: Create an instance of Sub (Sub *aSub = ...) in your Main, then you can acces to testView, something like: aSub.testView. But the changes are applied only for that 'Main' instance.

Comment: Thanks. I will do like that.

Comment: Who down vote this question? May I know why? I never down vote someone without giving any reason

Comment: Why can't you just do something like `Sub *sub = [[Sub alloc] init]; [sub setTestView:nil];` or `[sub testView];`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Because `testView` is encapsulated in another class, which is not instantiated within your `Main` class. You just have two different classes in one .h and .m file, respectively. You could create an instance of you subclass, but maybe you should reconsider your class design.

Btw, why do you do this? Why not splitting in two .h/.m files?

Comment: Hi..i have edited question. I can't have or I don't want to separate .h and .m file because I have many interfaces as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement Sub Class also same file (.m file)

```
@implementation Sub

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

then in Main init method will  be

```
@implementation Main

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

         Sub * s1 = [Sub new];
           // Now you can use s1.testView... and so on
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score -2):

Define a Sub variable in Main implementation and you can use testView of the variable.

But first, write

```
@class Sub;
```

before

```
@interface Main : UIViewController
```

.

Comment: Or they could just create a normal instance of it. When they do the `import` of the `.h` file into the `.m` file this will include the interface for `Sub` so all they need to do is `Sub *sub = [[Sub alloc] init];` doing `@class sub` is pointless -1